# Render Django formsets with AngularJS?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-forms

I want to move some parts of a main template into partials which shall not need django rendering (i.e. pure html/js) and use them in a ng-view in the main template.

However, the partials have Django formsets (using crispy) in them i.e useless without Django rendering.

Moreover, I do not want to write the complete formset HTML by hand.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you are going "client-side" for the interface, it makes more sense to ditch django forms/formsets and use something like django-rest-framework.

Comment: @PauloScardine I am suing django-rest-framework to serialize objects and related objects and send them as json. However, I am not sure if constructing the the whole formset HTML by hand is a good idea.

Comment: I do this all the time, creating angular formset directives.

Comment: @PauloScardine can you point/link me to "angular formset directives"

Comment: Angular formsets are just a combination of `ngForm` and `ngRepeat` iterating over the list of related models.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535094/angularjs-data-binding-in-ajax-html-response. It looks related to your question.

Comment: @PauloScardine +1. Not exactly what I am looking for, complete formset equivalent in ng but I think that will be the closest for now. I will have to write the management form elements and their binding in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a less or sass file too. This file, like your form, it's unusable without preprocessing.

Review code from https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/ for inspiration and look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ to learn how to do it.

Hard part is not do it because its easy make a static finder. Hard part is do it in development staging in a transparent way.

Answer (score 1):

You can request your partials from the server and put them into the $templateCache yourself using the filename as a key.

This way, when a partial .hmtl file is request, it will get the django rendered HTML.

```
$http.get('myForm.html', {cache:$templateCache});
```

You'll want to eagerly load these partial templates, as if the partial template is not in the cache, then it'll request the static html.

Hope this helps