# AngularJs data binding in ajax html response

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, angularjs

I'm using python/django as a backend with complex forms structure.
I got an angular controller which makes and request to get a suitable form. I found a django-angular package that adds 'ng-model' attribute to inputs. So I'm rendering a template with the form on the server side, and provide a response with HTML. Html as a response is probably not best practice, but it makes things a lot less time-consuming. 
So my issue is that I get HTML response with form and input with 'ng-model' attributes, but this binding just doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish that?
Here is just a sample of this html injection:
controller:

```
$scope.form = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.HTML);
```

template/view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="form"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create directive to `$compile` your html.

```
angular.module("app").directive('compilehtml', ["$compile", "$parse", function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            var parse = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function value() { return (parse($scope) || '').toString(); }

            $scope.$watch(value, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)($scope); 
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then add this directive

```
<div ng-bind-html="form" compilehtml></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kjmqkptx/)**

Comment: Thanks, that went smooth, i have forgotten about this, and I'm currently using angular from time to time, and decided to inculcating it to my work on daily basis. Thanks again!