# Angularjs inject html which contains 2 way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently injecting html into my view with

```
<span ng-bind-html="injected"></span>

$scope.injected = $sce.trustAsHtml("<input type='hidden' value='{{query}}' name='q'>");
```

But the data binding isn't getting initialised. Not 100% sure if I need to run it through something else before injecting it in the page.

Comment: [You need to compile your html.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535094/angularjs-data-binding-in-ajax-html-response/25535684#25535684)

Comment: Why this html needs to be injected? what it cannot be a directive template?

Comment: Thanks dasu908, exactly what I needed. 

Dalorzo: The input I inject depended on other things in a form being set on a form.

Comment: @user3985676 something like this do you mean [Online Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6kB4PunxgNTy8NtNCeZ?p=preview)