# how to set json response html(string) from controller to Angular UI?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ng-bind-html

Its printing html as it is(non html formatted data is shown in UI)
 Tried with ng-bind-html but didnt work
 Also tried using https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535684/6050814 not worked

````
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://.../req/get',
        data: '{"source":"careers","code":"","reqId":406}'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(JSON.stringify(response.data.reqDetailsBO.reqTitle));
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.reqDetailsBO.jdDisplay));
        //$scope.content = JSON.stringify(response.data.reqDetailsBO.jdDisplay)```;           
    });
````

//following is my html

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
```

//these are dependencies I am injecting

angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic.cloud','ngSanitize'])

//following is data I am trying to bind with

`<span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; 
   max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; 
   visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
 Notification
 </span>`

Comment: show us what u tried so far

Comment: Try $sce service with trustAsHtml(String) method or give your code snippet

Comment: and the html code

Comment: tried $sce @GitaramKanawade not working

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I have updated question

Comment: can u also post the result of `response.data.reqDetailsBO.reqTitle`

Comment: create a sample plnkr. add `bindHtmlCompile` directive and try it https://plnkr.co/edit/uF30O3EH3toQT3qfDkth?p=preview

Comment: thank you for reply but not working..